# Handling PubNub channel groups limit

Tags: node.js, chat, pubnub

**Context:**

We are working on a chat application using PubNub for real-time communication.

PubNub allows 2000 channels in a single channel group, after that you can subscribe up to 10 groups by connection.

The problem we currently have is that our backend sort of needs to be subscribed to every existing channel (through groups) because we have a Bot that reacts to commands.

We handle this connections in node.js, however when adding channels to a group PubNub does not error when adding more than 2000 channels with `channel_group_add_channel`, instead it returns a 200 response, and just takes out one previous channel (not sure which).

Because of this, I need to check whats the current number of channels in a group, and if its full - start a new group.

**The problem:**

We can get multiple simultaneous user registering, meaning new channels added that our bot needs to subscribe to.

Pseudo code to check if we can add more channels to the current group.

```
addChannel(channel) {
    group.canAdd()
      .then(group.add(channel));
}
```

`canAdd` would use `channel_group_list_channels` to check how many channels are currently in the group. Because of the async nature of javascript we have a race condition:

- current group has 1999 channels
- call `addChannel` twice
- both calls to `channel_group_list_channels` could return 1999 channels
- we add the first channel (group is now 2000)
- we add the second channel because we think we can
- some channel gets pushed out of the group (bad).

Is there a way we can workaround this without degrading performance?

Note that even having a counter in something like Redis would have the same issue, since the problem is concurrency.

Comment: This is an advanced use case (fan-in) and you should contact [PubNub Support](http://www.pubnub.com/support) to be put in contact with a Solution Architect. And we have a much more robust way - [PubNub BLOCKS feature coming soon](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/) for you to implement this that does not require you server to subscribe to every single channel.

Comment: By the way, the strategy (high level version) would be to instantiate multiple PUBNUB instances where each could subscribe to 10 channel groups with 2000 channels in each. However, PubNub Channel Groups does not magically make network, CPU and RAM constraints on your server go away. You still have to consider how many messages your server(s) can consume at once before it chokes or just can't keep up. This is what the PubNub global Data Stream Network has to do for 1000's of customers (billions of clients, 100's billions of transactions across many data centers) - to be continued...

Comment: So the solution is a distributed computing challenge to do what you want to do but we can help you with that. And PubNub Blocks will make this unnecessary. Please do contact us and we'll make this happen!

Comment: Thanks @CraigConover ill get in touch with support on monday!

Comment: Please add this SO link to your post to support so we can double back and provide answer here as appropriate.

Comment: so, we are changing our approach to this, I am leaving the question open as I think its still a valid question.

Comment: It is valid, just not recommended. When BLOCKS is finally available, your question will be answered for sure. I would be curious what your new approach is.

Comment: **[PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/products/functions/)** is the new term, we used to call it PubNub BLOCKS.

Answer (score 1):

## Create Chatbots Using PubNub Functions

The real question was about subscribing to thousands of channels on your server but Functions was brought up as the solution which prompted the asker to mention the use of chatbots.

*Long overdue answer for this question...*
[PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/products/functions/) have been around for over a year now and building a chatbot is simple when you can tap into any chat bot services: [IBM Watson](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks-catalog/pubnub-tutoring-bot), [Gupshup](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks-catalog/gupshup-bot-and-chatbot-messaging) and [so many others out there](https://chatbotsjournal.com/25-chatbot-platforms-a-comparative-table-aeefc932eaff).

PubNub Functions allow you to tap into the message and alter it, encode it, reject it, redirect, whatever you need to do to it, as the message is flying through the PubNub Network without the requirement of hitting your server(s). You simply implement some code in a Function module that will be executed within the PubNub Network based on different messaging events: publish, presence and you can even setup [endpoints](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/announcing-pubnub-functions-and-endpoints/).

For more resources on creating chatbots:

- [Chatbots & PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/chatbots-and-pubnub/)
- [Create a Chatbot in Under 10 Minutes Using PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-a-chatbot-with-pubnub-functions/)
- [Build a Realtime Chatbot with the Gupshup BLOCK](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-a-realtime-chatbot-with-gupshup/)

Comment: Not sure the downvote was completely justified, because the question was suggesting a design pattern that is challenging to implement. The recommendation to use Functions reduces the complexity of implementation. Perhaps the way I answered just didn't seem to apply. But I'd like your perspective how it should have been answered or how I should reword my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Our team ended up to refuse to use PubNub channels because of the same reason (and couple of others).

Our brief story:

We have NodeJS component which use PubNub. Over the time our component subscribe to more and more PubNub channels (around 400 per day). After 1 - 2 days we had to restart our component because it stopped to work. It turns out one PubNub instance just stopped to work after some amount of channels.
So we looked at PubNub channels and we faces with same race condition issue. Also we discovered strange behaviour of PubNub groups SDK. For example you cannot add more than 1800 channels in one call, you have to do 2 calls (1700 in first and + 300 in second, for example). Wtf? Docs says you can add up to 2000 channels.

Instead we implemented pool of PubNub instances, each described up to 100 channels. And it works perfectly. This is not recommended approach, but what else should you do in the lack of options?

Comment: For the record, your implementation is not "not recommended", necessarily, it just isn't the first recommendation we would push and it is not an implementation that is typical (server side subscribe is an edge case that Functions often provide best practice, but not always). As you stated, with Channel Groups, there is a limit on the number of channels you can add per call, but it very well may be that you hit a URI length limit but possibly is an actual PubNub API limit. Docs team has been notified of your feedback to be more transparent about that.

Comment: @CraigConover Yeah, good point about URI length, didn't think about it. One more thing about Group Channels: when you have 1999 channels in Group and you add another 100 channels then JS SDK replies: ok. But actually you still have same 1999 channels in this group that you have initially.

Comment: It should hold 2000, not 1999, but you are right. There isn't any "error" that tells you that you went over the limit. I have already logged an issue against that. In fact, I have logged some features with respect to events about adds, removes, limits, etc. Hope they are something we provide in the future. If you have any issues or suggestions about this or anything, let PubNub Support know and we can provide assistance. Here is fine, too, but you may have some proprietary code/issues you need to discuss.